# I cannot convert my list to a lower triangular matrix

Tags: r

I have two (False and True) lower triangular matrices. I would like to convert all the true values by my chosen number. I wrote the code but it does not work. Yhe given example is very similar to my problem (very complicated).

Here is my code:

```
> Matrix
[[1]]
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

[[2]]
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
np1 <- 10 
np2 <- 10
np <-list(np1, np2)
```

Here is the numbers that need to take the places of the `TRUE` values.

```
new <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

To do so, I wrote this code:

```
new1 <- lapply(1:2, function(i) matrix(0, 5, 5))
new1 <- lapply(1:2, function(i){new1[[i]][Matrix[[i]]]  <- new[[i]][1:np[[i]]]})
```

Comment: the way of defining `lapply` with the `new1` keeps it as a vector and that why it does not covert to matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
new1 <- lapply(1:2, function(i) matrix(0, 5, 5))
new1 <- lapply(1:2, function(i){new1[[i]][Matrix[[i]]][]  <- 1:np[[i]]; new1[[i]]})
new1
```

You missed the empty `[]` that forces `R` to keep the dimensions of the object, in this case the 5x5 matrices `new1`. Also, the anonymous function in the second `lapply` needs to return something, so maybe the following exact equivalent is more readable.

```
new1 <- lapply(1:2, function(i){
            new1[[i]][Matrix[[i]]][]  <- 1:np[[i]]  # note the last []
            new1[[i]]
        })
```